# Get Socket Server to listen for external Connections

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, server

I was wondering how i can manage that my Socket Server, that listens on port 3333 and for any incoming IP Addresses can listen for external connections. On my local network it all works fine, but if people try to connect to the server from another router they cant connect, i already added a Exception for my Server.exe in the Firewall and opened the Port 3333 on my router. Is there anything else i have to do?
Any help is appreciated

EDIT:
Server Code(C#):

```
private static Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
private static List<Socket> clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
private const int PORT = 3333;
private static byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
private static Random random = new Random();
private static int connectedClients = 0;

private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
{
    Socket current = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
    int received;

    try
    {
        received = current.EndReceive(AR);
    }
    catch (SocketException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client " + connectedClients + " Disconnected! (Forced)");
        current.Close();
        clientSockets.Remove(current);
        return;
    }
    byte[] recBuf = new byte[100];
    Array.Copy(buffer, recBuf, received);
    string text = getText(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf));
    if (text != "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Recieved: " + text);
    }
    if (current.Connected)
        current.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 100, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
}

private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
{
    Socket socket;

    try
    {
        socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException)
    {
        return;
    }

    clientSockets.Add(socket);
    socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 100, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, socket);
    connectedClients++;
    Console.WriteLine("Client " + connectedClients + " Connected! [" + IPAddress.Parse(((IPEndPoint)socket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString()) + "::" +
        ((IPEndPoint)socket.RemoteEndPoint).Port.ToString() + "]");
    serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
}

private void setupServer()
{
    SocketPermission perm = new SocketPermission(NetworkAccess.Accept, TransportType.Tcp, ""/*Here would sit my IPv4*/, PORT);
    perm.Assert();
    serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT));
    serverSocket.Listen(10);//0
    Console.WriteLine("Server Started!");
    Console.WriteLine("Listening for Clients...");
    serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
}

private void CloseAllSockets()
{
    foreach (Socket socket in clientSockets)
    {
        socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        socket.Close();
    }

    serverSocket.Close();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Title = "Server";
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Program prgrm = new Program();
    prgrm.setupServer();

    Console.ReadLine();
    prgrm.CloseAllSockets();
}
```

Comment: Do you have a static IP address?

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov it's static, i run the Server on my PC with no VPN and i let the Clients connect to my IPv4

Comment: Then add some code if possible. It should work with an open port.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov Updated OP!

Comment: Stupid question: Do you launch your application as admin? If not, try it.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov ohh actually i only launched in debug yet... I swear if thats the problem -_-

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov okay, that wasn't the problem, any other ideas!?

Comment: At least I don't see anything suspicious. Can't check it right now.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov Okay thanks for your help tho :)